# Facebook Response to JSON Object

Tags: android, json, facebook-graph-api

I need to either convert my facebook Response to a JSON Object or find another way to use the response in my code.

I've successfully printed my facebook api Response to the log using this:

```
Log.d("Friend Response in DIB: ", FriendResponse.toString());
```

Which gives me this:

```
06-09 14:02:33.706: D/Friend Response in DIB:(12421): {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"data":[{"id":"1402927803328937","name":"Open Graph Test User"},{"id":"1402874766667901","name":"Jane Dickson"}],"paging":{"next":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/v2.0\/277976949048048\/friends?format=json&access_token=CAAKsYnmrEh0BAGhTzCUOr6r3zMH7tt1mouEXrqsAi2fh1nYK1d1w5iSvBQEjCupMB1SA9f8G9GyAm41Bct0qwnXnHr4H81eHRHQaoEUrm9JhqRk2LNN260mZCNJwiuiqxX24zHrBINqZCcyh9VzsCM7PO2UKGfEJOcxmEhAZCl9v8XrcrBIkaeGNRC7zh7hZASZADRMTACaRUZApjkjyAuFxSWflkqMldfISgz4Lvi2gZDZD&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=enc_Aey9afbBKXSo8gtNoFOb5eEu4paCRUYRSWIG0v3nSeCgpCIWIj7O-gHnmemCVpr7hQgH--aTwM6-lZA6MyqEfF6H"}}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}
```

This information is correct, and now I need to put the **id** and **name** of each returned user into it's own list item in a list view.

I have a code which does this already, except it gets the information from a url using makeHttpRequest.

How do I convert my facebook Response type into a type that will work with this code instead of the makeHttpRequest? :

```
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_videos, "POST", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        Log.d("Friend Response in DIB: ", FriendResponse.toString());


        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
```

etc...

All help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the official Facebook docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/).

If you do an asynchronous (`Request.executeAsync()`)request, you'll use a `Request.Callback` with an `onCompleted(Response response)` method. If you do a request in series (be sure you're not on the main thread), the `Response` will be the value returned by the `Request.executeAndWait()` method.

From the `Response` object, you can call `response.getGraphObject().getInnerJsonObject()`. Use the Graph Explorer tool to get a better idea of the structure of the JSON you get from the API call.

Comment: Thank you so much! response.getGraphObject().getInnerJsonObject() was exactly what I needed.